# Flux Limiter for 2D Discontinuous Galerkin FEM

Tags: finite-element-method, continuity, galerkin-methods, transport-equation

I want to learn about implementing convection-diffusion simulations using discontinuous Galerkin (DG) finite element methods to solve
$$
\dfrac{\partial c}{\partial t} = \nabla \cdot \mathbf{J},
$$
for species $c$ with diffusion coefficient $D$ within a fluid flowing with velocity $\mathbf{u}$ where $\mathbf{J} = D \nabla c - \mathbf{u} c$, such as in [this example](https://github.com/FEniCS/dolfin/blob/master/demo/undocumented/dg-advection-diffusion/python/demo_dg-advection-diffusion.py). The domain I'm solving this in has a sharp/shock discontinuity in it and my simulation is oscillating at this discontinuity. This behavior is expected, from what I've [found](http://folk.ntnu.no/leifh/teaching/tkt4140/._main074.html), and it seems like a flux limiter would solve this issue and allow my solution to remain within the realm of realistic values. The part I'm working through with is how to actually implement the flux limiter in my simulation. How would would I implement such a correction (in 2D or 3D) in code using a DG finite element method? Any help would be welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Leveque's books or Hestaven's recent text. Both of these will help you understand limiters better.

They also provide code examples (online) for you to see how they implement limiters.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion--I looked at the Hestaven book and it was pretty helpful!

I'm now bumping into an additional challenge that I haven't been able to find a lot about; namely the difference between using a conservative and non-conservative formulations for the advection term. Would using one or the other be preferable? I've seen the non-conservative form used when a fluid is incompressible, but I was wondering how the difference in integrating by parts after multiplying by the test function or before (i.e. using grad(v) vs v in that term), would manifest.

Comment: In conservative form the IBP is trivial, but you are right- in nonconservative form aka convection form aka sequilinear form you have to be careful.  For the scalar case (and more rarely for the systems case) you sometimes get lucky and there is an equivalent conservation form.  The first thing to consider is whether or not you care about conservation for your variables.